# How to await fields before processing the file stream in multipart form

Tags: node.js, stream, promise, busboy

I'm using SendGrid for receiving files via email. SendGrid parses the incoming emails and sends the files in a multipart form to an endpoint I have set up.

I don't want the files on my local disk so I stream them straight to Amazon S3. This works perfect.

But before I can stream to S3 I need to get hold of the destination mail address so I can work out the correct s3 folder. This is sent in a field named "to" in the form post. Unfortunately this field sometimes arrives after the files are arriving, hence I need a way to await the to-field before I'm ready to take the stream.

I thought I could wrap the onField in a promise and await the to-field from within the onFile. But this concept seems to lock it self up when the field arrives after the file.

I'm new to booth streams and promises. I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to do this.

This is the non working pseudoish code:

```
function sendGridUpload(req, res, next) { 
  var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

  var awaitEmailAddress = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated) {
      if(fieldname === 'to') {
        resolve(val);
      } else {
        return;
      }
    });
  });


  busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {

    function findInbox(emailAddress) {
      console.log('Got email address: ' + emailAddress);

      ..find the inbox and generate an s3Key
      return s3Key;
    }

    function saveFileStream(s3Key) {
      ..pipe the file directly to S3
    }

    awaitEmailAddress.then(findInbox)
    .then(saveFileStream)
    .catch(function(err) {
      log.error(err)
    });
  });

  req.pipe(busboy);
}
```

Comment: * facepalm * At some stage in a rewrite I managed to remark the onData event. Without onData there will be no data to the stream. After reinstating the onData event it actually seems to work. But I would be really interested in comments from someone more knowledgeable. Is this an ok solution?

Comment: Also.. with this solution I'm loading up the internal buffer in the stream until I get the email address and release the stream through to S3. After some testing it seems to be couple of 100k up to a MB. How big can the internal stream buffer grow without getting me into trouble?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this working. The solution is not very pretty, and I have actually switched to another concept (described at the end of the post).

To buffer the incoming data until the "to"-field arrives I used *stream-buffers* by @samcday. When I get hold of the to-field I release the readable stream to the pipes lined up for the data.

Here is the code (some parts omitted, but essential parts are there).

```
var streamBuffers = require('stream-buffers');

function postInboundMail(req, res, next) {
  var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers});

  //Sometimes the fields arrives after the files are streamed.
  //We need the "to"-field before we are ready for the files
  //Therefore the onField is wrapped in a promise which gets
  //resolved when the to field arrives
  var awaitEmailAddress = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated) {
      var emailAddress;

      if(fieldname === 'to') {
        try {
          emailAddress = emailRegexp.exec(val)[1]
          resolve(emailAddress)
        } catch(err) {
          return reject(err);        
        }
      } else {
        return;
      }
    });
  });


  busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    var inbox;

    //I'm using readableStreamBuffer to accumulate the data before
    //I get the email field so I can send the stream through to S3
    var readBuf = new streamBuffers.ReadableStreamBuffer();

    //I have to pause readBuf immediately. Otherwise stream-buffers starts
    //sending as soon as I put data in in with put().
    readBuf.pause();

    function getInbox(emailAddress) {
      return model.inbox.findOne({email: emailAddress})
      .then(function(result) {
        if(!result) return Promise.reject(new Error(`Inbox not found for ${emailAddress}`))

        inbox = result;
        return Promise.resolve();
      });
    }

    function saveFileStream() {
      console.log('=========== starting stream to S3 ========= ' + filename)

      //Have to resume readBuf since we paused it before
      readBuf.resume();

      //file.save will approximately do the following:
      // readBuf.pipe(gzip).pipe(encrypt).pipe(S3)
      return model.file.save({
        inbox: inbox,
        fileStream: readBuf
      });
    }

    awaitEmailAddress.then(getInbox)
    .then(saveFileStream)
    .catch(function(err) {
      log.error(err)
    });


    file.on('data', function(data) {
      //Fill readBuf with data as it arrives
      readBuf.put(data);
    });

    file.on('end', function() {
      //This was the only way I found to get the S3 streaming finished.
      //Destroysoon will let the pipes finish the reading bot no more writes are allowed
      readBuf.destroySoon()
    });
  });


  busboy.on('finish', function() {
    res.writeHead(202, { Connection: 'close', Location: '/' });
    res.end();
  });

  req.pipe(busboy);
}
```

I would really much like feedback on this solution, even though I'm not using it. I have a feeling that this can be done much more simple and elegant.

**New solution:**
Instead of waiting for the to-field I send the stream directly to S3. I figured, the more stuff I put in between the incoming stream and the S3 saving, the higher the risk of loosing the incoming file due to a bug in my code. (SendGrid will eventually resend the file if I'm not responding with 200, but it will take some time.)

This is how I do it:

1. Save a placeholder for the file in the database
2. Pipe the stream to S3
3. Update the placeholder with more information as it arrives

This solution also gives me the opportunity to easily get hold of unsuccessful uploads since the placeholders for unsuccessful uploads will be incomplete.

//Michael